# Pre-compile numba cuda kernels (non-jit)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gpu, jit, numba

Hi I am using numba to write some kernels with the `@cuda.jit` decorator. I have 8 CPU threads each calling a kernel on 1 of 2 GPU devices. (`cpu_idx % len(cuda.gpus)` to be specific)

I believe each CPU thread is compiling the kernel, which takes up a lot of time relative to the time it takes for the kernel to process an entire image. Ideally it should be only compiled once for all the CPU threads to use. But I can't initialize any cuda gpu code before forking with `multiprocessing.Pool` because cuda doesn't like that.

So is there a way to pre-compile cuda kernels? I don't want just-in-time compilation

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eager Compilation to pre-compile the CUDA kernel for a given signature: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html?highlight=eager#eager-compilation

Note that the CUDA backend only supports a single signature for Eager Compilation (whereas the CPU target supports multiple), and that Eager-compiled kernels don't check types when you call the kernel. This results in a faster launch, but opens up the possibility of un-noticed user error by allowing argument types to mis-match between the compiled kernel and what is passed in.

However, noting from your question that you're using multiple processes rather than threads, you will still have an issue as you'd have to pre-compile and then fork, which CUDA still wouldn't like. Is it possible for you to use threads in your application with the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) instead?

A side question: if the runtime of your application / GPU kernel is so short that the compilation time is the dominating factor, does using a GPU make sense for your application? Once you have processed one image in each thread, even when JIT compiling, there won't be a compilation overhead for that thread again - for subsequent launches, the kernel will be retrieved from the cache. If you were processing many images, the compilation time would become negligible in the overall runtime.